# jQuery: fadeout and scrollto

Tags: jquery, scroll, visibility, fade

I've created a website using Bootstrap.
For example. We want to sell chairs.
Now we want to expand, and we want to sell tables, too.

I want to switch the whole content, depending of the choise of the customer.

This is a onepager-website. You can see the whole content scrolling from the top to the bottom. 
There are several sections like that.

```js
$('#contentfilter1').click(function(e) {
  $('#content1').fadeOut('slow',
    function() {
      $('#content2').fadeIn();
    });
  $('#content1nav').fadeOut('slow',
    function() {
      $('#content2nav').fadeIn();
    });
  $.scrollTo('.sec3', 1000);
  return false;
});
$('#contentfilter2').click(function(e) {
  $('#content2').fadeOut('slow',
    function() {
      $('#content1').fadeIn();
    });
  $('#content2nav').fadeOut('slow',
    function() {
      $('#content1nav').fadeIn();
    });

  $.scrollTo('.sec1', 1000);
  return false;

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="start">
  <button class="btn" id="contentfilter2">Change to Content 1</button>
  <button class="btn" id="contentfilter1">Change to Content 2</button>
</div>
<div id="content1">
  <section id="sec1" class="sec1">
    <p>This is section1</p>
  </section>

  <section id="sec2" class="sec2">
    <p>This is section2</p>
  </section>
</div>

<div id="content2" style="display:none;">
  <section id="sec3" class="sec3">
    <p>This is section3</p>
  </section>

  <section id="sec4" class="sec4">
    <p>This is section4</p>
  </section>
</div>
<footer>
<p>Footer content</p>
</footer>
```

When I click on "Change to Content 2" Content1 disappears and Content2 apperears. Fine. 
Now the script should scroll to the first section with content. In my case to "Section 3".
But the script scroll to the bottom of the page. The script doesn't stop. The scroll bar is at the bottom.

When I scroll up to the choosing-section and click on "Change to Content 2" again, the website scrolls to the right section.
There must be the problem, that the right section cannot be found after the first click. After it's visible, It's working fine.

Anyone an idea, how I could fix the problem?
Do I have to separate the script? First show the new content, then scroll to the start of the content?

Comment: your description of the problem is quite unclear. please better describe it

Comment: Let me try. My english is not the best ;) I give you an example. I've got a website. It's a onepager, where you can scroll from the top to the bottom. One section after another. The whole knowledge of creating and selling chairs.

Now we want to share our knowledge about creating other furniture.
We don't want to show the chair stuff. So the customer can choose at the top. Chairs or Tables.

Depending on the choise, the content switches.

The script should scroll to the start of the right content, but it scrolls to the absolute end.
When I click again on the content choose button, it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to add a line to your jQuery after the fading happens, like this:

```
$('#contentfilter2').click(function(e) {
  $('#content2, #content2nav').fadeOut('slow',function() {
     $('#content1, #content1nav').fadeIn();
  });
  $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$('#content1').offset().top - 20}, 'slow');
  return false;
});
```

This will scroll the page to the top of the "content1" section. You could choose to leave out the "-20" part from `.offset().top` or you can make that any number you wish -- it basically will go 20 pixels above the section you want, to accommodate for any navigation elements or for any space you want to leave there.

Best of luck to you!